# Integration by change of variables

Tags: integration

Let's have two functions $y(x)$ and its derivative $y'(x)$. We also have three functions $f(y)$, $g(y')$ and $h(x)$. I need to evaluate the following integrals but am not sure if I can do it as stated below:

$$\int f'(y)g(y')dx = \int f'(y)g(y')\frac{dx}{dy}dy \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{g(y')}{y'}\int f'(y)dy = \frac{g(y')}{y'}[f(y)+C_1]$$

$$\int h(x) dx = \int h(x) \frac{dx}{dy}dy \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{h(x)}{y'} \int dy = \frac{h(x)}{y'}(y + C_2)$$

Here, $y'=dy/dx$ and $C_1, C_2$ are constants. In my case, $y(x)$ is a single-valued function but $x(y)$ is not. I am not sure if I can use the change of variables in this case.